# Getting a jquery function to work with an ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, redactor

The Following text area is generated via an ajax call. But the redactor (text editor) is not working. I know i have to blur (or somehow refresh) but i've tried and tried but cant get the scripts to work. Any help?

```
<textarea sname='content' id='redactor'>Ajax updated content</textarea>


$(document).ready(function() {

    var buttons = ['html', 'formatting', 'bold', 'italic', 'deleted', 'unorderedlist', 'orderedlist', 'outdent', 'indent', 'link', 'horizontalrule'];

    $('#redactor').redactor({
        focus: true,
        buttons: buttons,
        maxHeight: 500
    });

});



 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "phpVars/ajaxUpload.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        $(".the-return").html(
         data["form"]
        );  
      }

    });
```

the above is the ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can place the code inside a function:

```
function loadEditor()
{
    var buttons = ['html', 'formatting', 'bold', 'italic', 'deleted', 'unorderedlist', 'orderedlist', 'outdent', 'indent', 'link', 'horizontalrule'];

    $('#redactor').redactor({
        focus: true,
        buttons: buttons,
        maxHeight: 500
    });
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "phpVars/ajaxUpload.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(data)
    {
        $(".the-return").html( data["form"] );
        loadEditor();
    }
});
```

and after ajax response, you can call this function. Hope this helps.

Comment: `and after ajax response` i guess you mean in ajax `success` callback

Comment: so do i simply add loadEditor(); within  success: function(data) { } ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because when the redactor's function is loaded, the text area don't have the data yet. You can try to insert this function into the ajax function or set the data provided by ajax to a global variable.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what $(".the-return") refers to, but if you want to update the content of textarea#redactor on ajax:success - you should do it via redactor API:

```
success: function(data) {
  $("#redactor").redactor('code.set', data["form"] );
}
```